# Talend - How to loop over Date of Birth till the Current Year using tloop or tmap?

Tags: talend

I have a requirement where I am giving Date of Birth from tRowGenerator. I want to loop till the current year i.e. from date of birth to current year and display values in tlogrow.

I'm able to print Years, Months, seconds, M seconds difference using TalendDate diff function but not in a loop.

I tried figuring out a solution but could not succeed. Can anyone help me out?

Total result in 1 log:

[image]

Comment: What values do you want to display ? days ? months ?

Comment: I want to display Years, Months, Days, Hours, minutes and seconds for every year from date of birth till the current year in a loop.

Comment: What you can do is calculate the difference between the dates in seconds, store the result in a global variable, then use tLoop from 1 to the total seconds and for each step, add a second to the initial date and show it